# Как получить весь тэг с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как получить весь тэг с помощью javascript?
Т.е. если я делаю getElementsByTagName('a'), то в массиве будут не полностью строки '<a>...</a>', а только сами адреса, куда ведут эти ссылки, а мне нужен полностью HTML.

Условия - без использования сторонних библиотек.

Comment: в массиве(строго говоря, это не массив а nodeList) DOM элементы а не адреса. у каждого такого элемента есть свойство outerHTML

Comment: > есть свойство outerHTML

но далеко не во всех браузерах :)

Comment: интересное условие -  без использования сторонних библиотек. С JQuery одной строчкой можно решить все проблемы (что вам наверное и без меня известно )) )

Comment: а innerHTML точно во всех :)

Comment: но далеко не во всех браузерах :)

стоит ли поддерживать такие браузера?, и вообще на некоторых нету JS

Comment: В тех браузерах, где outerHTML не поддерживается, его можно реализовать через XMLSerializer. Смотрите мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 2):

Берем все элементы, помещаем их в контейнер, возвращаем `innerHTML` контейнера:

```
function getOuterHtml(element_or_set, exclude_deep)
    {
    if (element_or_set.cloneNode)    // или (element_or_set.tagName)
        element_or_set = new Array(element_or_set);

    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');

    for (var i = 0; i < element_or_set.length; i++)
        {
        wrapper.appendChild(element_or_set[i].cloneNode(!exclude_deep));
        }

    return wrapper.innerHTML;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5AnrW/5/

Comment: можно наверное и не клонировать, туда-сюда просто вставить, это наверное будет быстрее, чем создавать элемент.

Comment: Не понял. А как ты собираешься узнать, где он был до перемещения во `wrapper`? В смысле, точную позицию.

Comment: по свойству parent, а погоди да, точно положение же важно...
тогда может его стабом зареплейсить, надо подумать....

Comment: ну если с replace то [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/gzfcG/), но  [медленнее](http://jsperf.com/cloned-vs-noncloned-outerhtml)

Comment: Крутой сервис! И крутой тест :)

Я только сомневаюсь насчет `if (element_or_set.constructor !== NodeList)`. Это для случая, когда первым аргументом передан getElementById, к примеру. Верно ли делать такое сравнение с `NodeList`?

Comment: там на самом деле что в моем коде что в вашем - не работает в firefox (а у меня firebug чёт поломался чтобы задебажить почему)

Comment: FF говорит, что метод `element_or_set[i].cloneNode` не существует.
Все это как раз из-за моего этого сравнения с `NodeList`. `getElementsByTagName` должен возвращать объект `NodeList` — я уточнил на W3Schools (стало быть, это по стандарту? Еще раз уточнил [здесь][1]). А у FF это `HTMLCollection`. Так-то.

Все дело в первой же строке. Обновил код в ответе — теперь и в FF работает.

  [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html

Answer (score 1):

Может так подойдет?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function()
{
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

    var link = menu.innerHTML.match(/<a(.*)\/a>/gi);

    alert(link);
}
</script>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/" class="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contacts">Contats</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: По-моему, это все равно что приехать на отдых к океану, но купаться в бассейне

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить поддержку outerHTML:

```
var linkArray = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), 
    elemArray = [],
    len = linkArray.length;

// Включаем поддержку outerHTML, самая главная часть кода ;)
if (window.Node && window.XMLSerializer){
    Node.prototype.__defineGetter__('outerHTML', function() {
        return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this);
    });
}

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    elemArray[i] = linkArray[i].outerHTML;
}
alert(elemArray[0]);
```

Comment: только если outerHTML уже есть, его добавлять не надо